# How to implement segue on button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, crash

I'm building an iOS app.I have implemented Facebook and twitter integration in my app.

I am facing an problem in a viewcontroller i have button Next and implemented a push segue
on that button to go on next view,but my app crashed when i click on the Next button and got an error.

Error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'nextSport'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Here is Screenshot of storyboards:

Previous Image:
[image]

Present(new) image added:

[image]

This is my code:

```
            - (IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {
                   [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                  switch (state) {
                                      case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

                                              if (error) {

                                                  NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below


                                                  [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          // Handle error
                                                      }

                                                      else {
                                                          NSString *userName = [FBuser name];
                                                          NSLog(@"username===%@",userName);
                                                           NSLog(@"sesseion=%@",session);
                                                                                                                    }
                                                  }];

                                                  NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                                                  userName=user.first_name;
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                                         user.location[@"name"]]);
                                                  userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [user objectID]];
                                                  NSLog(@"image=%@",userImageURL);

                                               }
                                              [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"afterLogin" sender:nil];
                                          }];
                                          break;
                                          }
                                } ];
                        }
```

Comment: The source view controller (The one with the "next" button) needs to be embedded in a navigation controller in order to use a push segue

Comment: User has completely changed question form an issue about a crash when clicking a button, to a question about how to display a viewController after a facebook login request. These are 2 completely unrelated questions and should be asked separately, not changing it and asking the current people answering to also solve this issue

Comment: @Simon no my issues is not solved.

Comment: @Daljeet the original question you asked was solved. 3 hours ago you edited the question to include this facebook code. Your question was why is my app crashing and how do I fix it. That was answered, this question as it stands is 2 questions merged into one, which is not how stackoverflow is to be used. That is why I have voted for this question to be closed. If you wish to ask another question then feel free to do so. But include the ENTIRE question from the beginning and don't change the context after people have helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing to a `UINavigationController` but the viewController that is preforming the push should also be inside a `UINavigationController`. As the error suggests there was no `UINavigationController` to execute the segue 'nextSport'

Comment: Thanks @Simon,could you explain me more about viewController that is preforming the push should also be inside a UINavigationController,so i can crack this.

Comment: @Daljeet I'm not sure how else to explain this. You are calling a segue on viewController A, the segue is going to a UINavigationController which has viewController B as its root. viewController A should be the root of a UINavigationController and should be pushing directly to B, not pushing to a navController that contains B

Comment: thanks @Simon i have edited my question with a new image of my storyboards.But now what is happening when user logged in succesfully,its not able to go on next view whick i want.I also want when user logged in succesfully and come agin after closing the app it should be on next view not on the login screen.

Comment: @Daljeet I have no idea what you mean from that comment. The login is another question entirely. One that has been answered on stackoverflow many times. As for this, you didnt follow my instructions. I said remove the navigationController immediately after the next button and instead add one before the viewController with the next button. After you've done this, if the original question is not working, post detailed instructions of what is happening vs what should be happening. E.g. App opens on controller x, user clicks button y, result is crash. Expected result is it opens controller z

Comment: Simon, i have already done that Login view-->Navigation Controller-->NextView with next button-->ViewController but after logged in successfully i'm not able to go on next screen which is NextView with next button,but still on the Login view.

Comment: @Daljeet as I said in my previous comment this is a separate question. Your question is how to implement a segue on a button click, I have showed you what your problem was. Please upvote my answer and mark it as top answer. If you now need to know how to open a particular screen when the app opens, depending on if the user is logged in, this is a separate issue that should be asked in another question, although there are already many answers to it on stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63014/discussion-between-daljeet-and-simon-mcloughlin).

Comment: Simon i have posted my second problem framing a new question,please look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362649/how-to-perform-modalsegue

Answer (score 1):

You should shift place of the second(navigation controller) and the third(the controller's view that has next button) view controller in the image, because when you click the next button, there is no navigation controller for you to do the push.

Comment: From the image I am not certain if he is using a UITabbarController, if so, I think the UITabbarController should be embedded in a navigation controller. And remove other navigation controllers.

Comment: Right now i have not implemented any UITabbarController.

Comment: @Daljeet,a navigation controller manages the navigation of hierarchical content, it manages the currently displayed screens using the navigation stack, which is represented by an array of view controllers. so if you want to navigate forward(push from a button) or back, you have to embed your view controller inside a navigation controller or push the controller onto the navigation stack, right now, the view controller that has the next button is not on the navigation stack.

Comment: thanks @Carousel i have added navigation controller before the view as you said you can see in the image i have added new one.but now what is happening when user logged in succesfully,its not able to go on next view whick i want.

Comment: @Daljeet, try removing the navigation controller which is the second one from left, since you already have **one** navigation controller which is the fourth from left in the picture,you **only need one** `navigation controller` to manage all view controllers in the navigation stack. After removing, the first page and the third page(which has the next button) are on the navigation stack.

Comment: I have done that but still what i want that when user logged in successfully from facebook it should be on next view which i have implemented by a afterLogin segue as you can see in picture or in code.

Comment: @Daljeet, in this case, you should push your facebook login page on stack, try to move navigation controller to the right side of facebook page, then the segue will be effective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63006/discussion-between-daljeet-and-carouselmin).