# How to perform modalSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboardsegue, ibaction

I'm building an iOS app. I have integrated facebook login in my app and implemented modal segue
means when user logged in successfully it goes on next view.

I'm facing a problem that is after logged in i'm not able to go on next view.one thing more i'm not able to do that when user already logged in on my app through facebook and come back after closing the app it should be on Next ViewController not on login screen again.

Storyboard flow is:

> Login screen --> Modal Segue --> Navigation Controller --> Next
>   ViewController

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                      switch (state) {
                                          case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                              [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

                                                  if (error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                                                  } else {
                                                      // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                      [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
                                                          if (error) {
                                                              // Handle error
                                                          } else {
                                                              NSString *userName = [FBuser name];
                                                              NSLog(@"username===%@",userName);
                                                              NSLog(@"sesseion=%@",session);
                                                          }
                                                      }];

                                                      NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                                                      userName=user.first_name;
                                                      NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                                                      NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                                                      NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);
                                                      NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                                                      NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                                                      NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                                      NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                                             user.location[@"name"]]);
                                                      userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [user objectID]];
                                                      NSLog(@"image=%@",userImageURL);

                                                  }
                                                  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"afterLogin" sender:sender];
                                              }];
                                              break;
                                      }
                                  } ];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"afterLogin"]) {
        PPla *image = [segue destinationViewController];
        PPla *name = [segue destinationViewController];
        name.proName = [NSString stringWithFormat:userName];
        image.proImage = userImageURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a lot of vital information from your question. What is the result of the print outs, are they working? give a sample output. I haven't used the facebook sdk before but the code looks very odd to me, looks like you are calling the same method twice `[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {`, please verify this is all correct. Is it getting to the `prepareForSegue` method? if not how far is it getting? lastly your `performSegueWithIdentifier` isn't inside the last completion block

Comment: its very possible this code is running before your facebook queries finish. Using a modal segue is generally to provide a popup, normally it would not be used to popup a navigation controller. I would recommend using a push segue unless you have a specific need for a modal.

Comment: @Simon i have applied push segue as well but it is not working.

Comment: i raised many other points in my comments apart from that one. Please read and respond to everyones questions  / comments in their entirety or nobody will waste there time to help you

Comment: yes Simon my code is reaching at prepareForSegue method.I'm new to iOS development and first time integrating facebook into any app.So help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this 
add this line your .h file

```
@property(strong ,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *userinfo;
```

.m file

```
add this `@synthesize userinfo`



    - (IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                          switch (state) {
                                              case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                                  [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

                                                      if (error) {
                                                          NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                                                      } else {
                                                          // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
                                                              if (error) {
                                                                  // Handle error
                                                              } else {
                                                                  NSString *userName = [FBuser name];
                                                                  NSLog(@"username===%@",userName);
                                                                  NSLog(@"sesseion=%@",session);
                                                              }
                                                          }];

 NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);


    [userinfo  setValue: [FBuser name] forKey:@"fbusername"];
//add here all your value which you want

      }
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"afterLogin" sender:sender];
                                                  }];
                                                  break;
                                          }
                                      } ];

    }


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;
   // NSLog(@"prepareForSegue:= %@", identifier);


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"afterLogin"]) {

        [segue.destinationViewController setID:userinfo];




    }


}
```

just add this method in your destination viewcontoller

```
-(void)setID:(NSMutableDictionary *)value;
{


     // all your details here

      NSLog(@"Got happy userinfo %@", value);

}
```

Comment: thanks @Sport, i have applied your code,but nothing is happening i am still on the login screen after logged in.If you need more information let me know.

Comment: please check -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender is called or not

Comment: have u set the identifier properly

Comment: yes -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender is called,But -(void)setID:(NSMutableDictionary *)value is not called because it is in the next view class which is not displaying right now.

Comment: -(void)setID:(NSMutableDictionary *)value; have add this in .h file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63040/discussion-between-sport-and-daljeet).